# Intuitive Explanation Relationship between Random Variable, Density function and Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

After slowly coming to grips with Random Variables and the distributions that they subscribe to (e.g. $X$ ~ $\mathcal{U}(0,1$)) , we introduced the notion of pdf, which I believe I understand in essence, but  I am rather confused when, for example, we are told that for the exponential distribution to parameter $\lambda > 0$

the density $f$ can be said to be $f(x):=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\chi_{[0,\infty[}(x)$.

I always thought that distributions were set according to a random variable. However, a random variable is not mentioned anywhere above.

My guess is that $f(x):=P(X \in \{x\})$, where $X$ is the random variable that actually has exponential distribution to parameter $\lambda$, rather than the density function $f$.

I need clarity on the terms, and perhaps an explanation on how it all fits together.

Comment: A random variable has a distribution, $P[X \le \alpha]$. Many variables may have the same distribution (for example all dice have essentially the same distribution). The density is one way of specifying the distribution (not all distributions have a density). Given a distribution (it must satisfy certain properties) one can construct a random variable having that distribution.

Comment: The density $f$ is not a probability; it is [probability per unit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok) of something. $f$ is the density of the random variable $X$, which as you say, has an exponential distribution.

Comment: @copper.hat what distributions do not have a density? discrete distributions?

Comment: Any discrete distribution (such as a coin toss). Also, a distribution may be, for example,  a mixture of discrete and continuous.

Comment: Strict terminology Distribution function, $P(X\le x)=\lambda\int_0^xe^{-\lambda u}du=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat can I ever write the expected value $\mathbb E[X]$ of the random variable $X$ as $\mathbb E[f]$ where $f$ is the Probability density?